# Composer not installing on Windows 7

Tags: php, composer-php, wampserver, php-openssl

I am using Windows 7 32 bit with `WAMP 2.4 & PHP 5.4.16`

I have enabled openssl in WAMP extension and also enabled in `php.ini` here `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16`

**When i try to install Composer i get following error**

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

I tried to disable windows firewall it still didn't work

Comment: Have you enabled openssl for command-line PHP as well?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your PHP package which does not have SSL enabled. To do this, edit `php.ini` and make sure this is added:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll.
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12 
and open php.ini file 
UnComment following extensions like remove ";" form beginning of line

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
```

and make sure that windows firewall is off

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried enabling the open_ssl extension via the WAMP interface it might not work. Go to the command prompt and type in `path` to find out the path to PHP. Go inside that folder and open up `php.ini` and remove `;` from the line which says `extension=php_openssl.dll.`

Let me know how it goes...